# Unable to save the plots in Octave using print and saveas command

Tags: octave

I am using Octave 3.6.4 on Window 7, I am not able to save the 9 plots which are generated using Octave scripts. I am using below commands to save the plots. Though sometime I am able to save the plots but all the saved plots are same which is similar to the last plot generated by the script. Why?

```
 pathfig = [path, '.png']; 
 print(h, '-dpng', pathfig,'-r100');
 saveas(h, pathfig, 'jpg');
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are only seemingly saving the last plot you generate, it is safe to say that your variable h is assigned to that last plot.

You will likely need to specify each figure you want to print.  For example, to get a handle to the first figure, you could do:

```
h1 = figure(1);
```

To get a handle to the second figure:

```
h2 = figure(2);
```

And separately use h1, h2, etc. in separate calls to saveas or print.  This is how I have done it in the past.

Comment: The value of h is from 1 to 9

Answer (score 0):

I am able to save the specific figures. The problem is, I was using graphics_toolkit as fltk when I switch to gnuplot then the print command is working properly, but there is issue with saveas command.